# In app purchase won´t remove ads immediately

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, nsuserdefaults

In my app you can remove the ads with an in app purchase. It works, however the ads wont disappear immediately. Does anyone know why?

Here´s my code:

The part where I save the buyers purchase:

```
- (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"isPurchased"];

[userDefaults synchronize];

NSString * productIdentifier = notification.object;
[_products enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(SKProduct * product, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([product.productIdentifier isEqualToString:productIdentifier]) {
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx 
inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        *stop = YES;
                }
```

The part where I load the buyers purchase with an if statement within viewDidLoad:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(![userDefaults boolForKey:@"isPurchased"])
{
    NSLog(@"Enter add start ");

CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height -
                             CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeBanner).height);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are only determining the sizing of the advertisement when loading the view. You'll need to adjust the sizing of the advertisement in the notification you receive in order for it to reflect immediately. For example, at the end of - (void)productPurchased:(NSNotification *)notification do this:

CGPoint origin = CGPointMake(0.0,
                             self.view.frame.size.height);

Then execute whatever frame setting code you have to set the ad in your current implementation.